# Latest OS / latest SDK

Tags: iphone, ipad

I've been doing my coding with Xcode 3.2.3
I've recently upgraded my iPad OS to 3.2.2.

Trying to run a provisioned development build from xcode on my iPad, I'm told:

The version of iPhone OS on “User’s iPad” does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS supported for development with this installation of the iPhone SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iPhone SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on User's iPad
3.2.2 (7B500)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
4.0 (8A293)
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0

Do I simply need to download the latest SDK (3.2.4)?
And will I be able to create distribution builds for submission to the App Store with this latest SDK?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, but not always, you need to download a new SDK any time you upgrade your iDevice OS to one newer than the SDK.

Comment: New SDK (3.2.4) fixed the issue with testing builds on the 3.2.2 iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you need to re-download the latest SDK Version which contains what is needed to build and run on your deice.

It's a bit... frustrating because of downloading (again) > 2.5 Go for ONE tiny tiny tiny change.

Download it and it will work ;-)